# How to set only one search input value with click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a search bar in which you can search and click on the search result. Right now I have a limit of 10 search results but the problem is that the search input value shows all 10 elements instead of the one that was clicked. I only want the clicked element or link to be set in the search bar. I'm assuming this doesnt have to be made in the server.

html

```
<div class="search-boxpost" id="searchboxpost">
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search..." />
<div class="resultpost" id="resultsearchpost"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
// the livesearch bar in makeapost
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search-boxpost input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function() {
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".resultpost");

        if (inputVal.length){
            $.get("includes/searchbar.inc.php", { game: inputVal }).done(function(data) {
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
                $('.resultpost').css('display', 'block');

                $(".search-boxpost").focusin(function () {
                    $('.resultpost').css('display', 'block');
                });               
            });
        } else {
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });


    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".resultpost", function() { 
        $(this).parents(".search-boxpost").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".resultpost").empty();
        $('.resultpost').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: The click event is targeting `.resultpost` when it should be targeting the children.

Comment: @Souleste What do you exactly mean? what elements are the children in this case?

Comment: Well I'm assuming that `.resultpost` contains a list of items but the click event is attached to `.resultpost` which is the container. Using `$(this).text()` will get all text from `.resultpost`.

Comment: **$(document).on("click", ".resultpost", function(){** should reference the element being clicked not its parent. So something like **$(document).on("click", ".resultpost li", function(){**

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, helped me a lot on understanding this one

Answer (score 0):

@Souleste and @imvain2 brought me the answers. All I needed to do was to reference the element being clicked which in this case the server sends back a `<p> $title </p>` message containing the search result and this is done with AJAX.

`.resultpost p` is correct:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".resultpost p", function(){
  $(this).parents(".search-boxpost").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
  $(this).parent(".resultpost").empty();
  $('.resultpost').css('display', 'none');
});
```